# Let Users Make a Feedback before Download File

Tags: views, nodes, webforms

I want to let users fill a form feedback about the node before downloading the file that attached to that node! like in Dialog or Popup, which modules should I use here?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Drupal coding skills I would use a custom form with a modal using the [OpenModalDialogCommand](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Ajax%21OpenModalDialogCommand.php/class/OpenModalDialogCommand/8.3.x). In the modal you can attach a form with a textarea and a submit button. On clicking the submit button the feedback from the textarea gets stored, the modal gets closed ([CloseModalDialogCommand](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Ajax%21CloseModalDialogCommand.php/class/CloseModalDialogCommand/8.3.x)) and a [BinaryFileResponse](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21BinaryFileResponse.php/class/BinaryFileResponse/8.3.x) gets returned.

I don't know of any contributed modules that provide this functionality.

P.S. I am assuming that you are using Drupal 8 here.

Comment: hello thank you so much for reply ! i4m not good in coding ! so will you please give more about this .... please

Comment: I will post back some sample code in a couple of hours provided that I was correct in assuming that you are using Drupal 8?